# unable to find .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos

I am using below command in Mac Finder -

```
nano .bash_profile
```

It does not open any file in TextEdit as per the online blogs are mentioning.

My OS is OS X 10.11.4

when i use `ls -al`, it gives command not found, maybe because I have used n incorrect `export PATH`

Comment: Why do you think running `nano` will start `TextEdit`? It won't, it will start `nano`. If you specifically want to open a file in your login directory, you should do `cd; ls -al` and you will see the names of all the files in your login directory, then you can choose one and open that. Your `bash` profile may be called `.profile`, by the way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I updated the question, with my system response.

Comment: Some versions of macOS don't have this file. It's completely normal for it not to exist.

Comment: @tripleee, If that is so, how can I can make my ls command work.

Currently its not working, gives me error as command not found.

Comment: Ok, try `export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin` for now till you get things working.

Comment: By the way, you need to type commands like these into `Terminal` not `Finder`. To start `Terminal`, hit `Cmd` and `Space` then type `Terminal` till it guesses you mean the `Terminal` app, then hit `Enter` or `Return`. That's called a `Spotlight Search`.